# Spring Eureka in integration tests

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, wiremock, testcontainers

We have a web service `A` (`Java 17`, `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign: 3.1.6`, `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client: 3.1.6`, `testcontainers: 1.18.0`, `wiremock: 2.35.0`) that calls service `B` using openfeign. Since service `B` is registered in Eureka we send a call into the `B` service using the openfeign client below:

```java
@FeignClient("SESSION-MANAGER")
public interface SessionManagerClient {

    @PostMapping(path = "/session/get", consumes = "application/json")
    Session getSession(SessionRequstBody sessionRequstBody);

}
```

Openfeign configuration (*we don't have any other openfeign configurations or beans*):

```yaml
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 600000
        readTimeout: 600000
        logger-level: basic
```

This code finds the appropriate service in Eureka by the `SESSION-MANAGER` name and sends the request. It works well in the environment.
But I don't quite understand how to mock this `/session/get` call (using wiremock) in integration tests. Because there is Eureka (implicitly) between the code call and the openfeign client. So because of it openfeign thinks about the `@FeignClient("SESSION-MANAGER")` as a host and sends such request `http://SESSION-MANAGER/session/get` leads to this error:

```java
[WARN ] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.069 [simpleMessageListenerContainer-2]  o.s.c.l.c.RoundRobinLoadBalancer - No servers available for service: SESSION-MANAGER
[DEBUG] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.070 [simpleMessageListenerContainer-2]  o.s.c.o.l.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient - Selected service instance: null
[WARN ] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.070 [simpleMessageListenerContainer-2]  o.s.c.o.l.RetryableFeignBlockingLoadBalancerClient - Service instance was not resolved, executing the original request
[ERROR] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.074 [simpleMessageListenerContainer-2]  c.o.t.s.s.MyService - Error in getting Session
feign.RetryableException: SESSION-MANAGER executing POST http://SESSION-MANAGER/session/get
    at feign.FeignException.errorExecuting(FeignException.java:268)
    ...
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SESSION-MANAGER
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    ...
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:121)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
[DEBUG] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.386 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook]  o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@748904e8, started on Mon Jun 26 13:56:49 EEST 2023
[INFO ] 2023-06-26 13:56:52.386 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook]  o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry - Unregistering application MY-SERVICE with eureka with status DOWN
```

The question is could you please help me understand what should I mock in this case? Should I directly mock a call to the service `B` or maybe I even should up the Eureka in Testcontainers and manage it on this level?

Eureka configuration:

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: "http://localhost:8761/eureka/"
  instance:
    statusPageUrl: "http://${eureka.hostname}/info"
    healthCheckUrl: "http://${eureka.hostname}/health"
    homePageUrl: "http://${eureka.hostname}/"
    nonSecurePortEnabled: true
```

Wiremock:

```java
WIREMOCK_SERVER.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo("/session/get"))
        .withRequestBody(WireMock.equalToJson(SESSION_MANAGER_REQUEST_BODY))
        .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .withBody(SESSION_MANAGER_RESPONSE))
);
```

Comment: There's an alternative to the answer below. You can use a static service instance list supplier you can use instead of registering wiremock with eureka. I'm on mobile or is point you to examples in spring cloud's own tests

Comment: Do you mean to implement a custom Feign client configuration? But then the Feign client will no longer rely on Eureka for service discovery, does not it? Instead, it will use the static list of service instances provided by the `ServiceInstanceListSupplier` bean.

Comment: No. I mean to do something like this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/98ccd635e0c98f5c6bf5b580d7db3f877bceddff/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/test/BaseWebClientTests.java#L139-L150 and this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/98ccd635e0c98f5c6bf5b580d7db3f877bceddff/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/test/BaseWebClientTests.java#L83 in your test. Disable eureka, but plug into the load balancer framework to point to a preconfigured HTTP service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@spencergibb shared a hint in a comment.

> No. I mean to do something like this github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/… and this github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/… in your test. Disable eureka, but plug into the load balancer framework to point to a preconfigured HTTP service.

I will put my solution here to make it answer visible to everyone.

The Spring presents the `@LoadBalancerClient` annotation to implement a client-side load balancer. There are two steps only.

Firstly, need to create the client-side load balancer:

```java
public static class TestClientLoadBalancer {

    private static final String SERVICE_ID = "session-service";

    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier staticServiceInstanceListSupplier() {
          return ServiceInstanceListSuppliers.from(SERVICE_ID,
                  new DefaultServiceInstance(SERVICE_ID + "-1", SERVICE_ID, "localhost", LOAD_BALANCER_PORT, false));
    }

}
```

Second step put it above the integration test:

```java
@WireMockTest
@Testcontainers
@LoadBalancerClient(name = "test-client-side-load-balancer", configuration = TestClientLoadBalancer.class)
public abstract class IntegrationBaseTest {
```

Also, I had to get a port for the client load balancer and I got it from wiremock server.

```java
public static int LOAD_BALANCER_PORT;

@BeforeAll
static void beforeAll() {
    LOAD_BALANCER_PORT = WIREMOCK_SERVER.getPort();
}
```